# Undefined variable in action route with parameter for laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

This is my view, and I want to pass r{{$i}}_selected to controller, but it gives me an error. Undefined variable: enterprise . How can I solve this?

```
<form name="frm-example" id="frm-example" 
    action="{{ route('pengawas_alokasi.store', $enterprise ) }}" 

    method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}


        <div class="table-responsive text-center">
            <table class="table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" id="myTable">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th class="text-center">#</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Nama Perusahaan</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <?php $i=1;?> @foreach($enterprises as $enterprise)
                 <tr>
                    {{--
                    <td></td> --}}
                    <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="r{{$i}}_selected" value="{{$enterprise->id}}">
                    </td>


                    <td>{{$i}}</td>

                    {{-- <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="nomor{{$i}}" value="{{$i}}" size="3">{{$i}}</td> --}}


                    <td>{{$enterprise->nama_perusahaan}}</td>
                    {{-- <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="nama_perusahaan{{$i}}" value="{{$enterprise->nama_perusahaan}}" size="3">{{$enterprise->nama_perusahaan}}</td> --}}

                </tr>
                <?php $i=$i+1;?> @endforeach
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" name="" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
        </div>
</form>
```

This is the controller that responsible to the view above

```
public function insert($id)
{
     $enterprises = Enterprise::get();      
     return view('pengawas.pengawas-insert-alokasi', compact('enterprises'));
}
```

This is the controller that should store the value that I want to retrieve in my view form

```
public function store_enterprise(Request $request){
//I'm not doing it yet    
dd($request);

}
```

Comment: you can pass the variable in an hidden input in form.

Comment: I already doing that, I wanna test if I can pass it with $enterprise variabel that defined in form, but I got an error  if I use  **action=" {{ route('pengawas_alokasi.store', $enterprise ) }} "**, If I comment this I got no error. The error is undefined variable

Answer (score 0):

because you are sending "enterprises" from your controller and you are trying to send "enterprise" in your form's action

Comment: I did that by the way, but I got another error. **Missing required parameters for [Route: pengawas_alokasi.store]**

Comment: can you show me the route for this in your web.php file?

Answer (score 0):

you can use hidden variable in your form instead of use URL variable :

```
<input type="hidden"  name="enterprise" value="{{$enterprise}}">
```

and in your controller :

```
public function insert(Request $request)
{
     //get enterprise value here
     $enterprise = $request->enterprise;

}
```

Comment: **insert** is to see the form view while **store_enterprise** is to store the values that I got from the form view. I think that function is for the **store_enterprise**, my problem here is I can't pass the value in the form view (for example r{{$i}}_selected) to other controller. In this case I used **action="{{ route('pengawas_alokasi.store', $enterprise ) }}"** to get the values but I got Undefined variable

Comment: why you make it as separated function if you can directly POST to your store_enterprise

Comment: because I just wanna store a few of it, I add checkboxes in the form, I wanna test it first (passing the checked values), but I got the error and stuck at there until right now.

Comment: actually, I also did it without parameter (without $enterprises), only the route, but I got **Missing required parameters for [Route: pengawas_alokasi.store]**